# how to use if condition on more than one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm new to python so I have 1 question about the "if" sentence. I have 3 variables and I need to show 1 message on the screen like the millage is"  ", look:

I have 3 city if i write 1 show the millage but if don't exist show "address not found try again"
when I use else like the below:

else:
print(Fore.GREEN + "\nAddress not Found, check address again")

show me the sentence "not found check again" but show the millage too, I don't know if I'm explaining ok, but if someone can help ill B thankful.

```
destino1 = "Tuscalosa AL"
destino2 = 'Warren OH'
destino3 = "Atlanta GA"


 if address in (destino1):
  print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles  ", "\033[34m","935 miles")

 if address in (destino2):
  print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles ", "\033[34m", "1600 miles")

 if address in (destino3):
  print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles ", "\033[34m", "1107 miles")        



 else:
   print(Fore.GREEN + "\nAddress not Found, check address again")
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking. could you post your code and the expected result?

Comment: oh im sorry i posted 1 pic let me try again

Comment: don't post your code as images. Put it as formatted code

Comment: yeah! its better now, i think

Comment: Not directly related, but those `address in (destino2)` checks are misleading at best. Those will check if string `address` is a substring of (in this case) `destino2`. If you want to compare to multiple alternatives, make sure to use an actual tuple `(destino,)` or list `[destino]`, not just a string in parens. If you want to check equality, use `==`.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this kind of structure:

```py
if address in (destino1):
    print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles  ", "\033[34m","935 miles")
elif address in (destino2):
    print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles ", "\033[34m", "1600 miles")
elif address in (destino3):
    print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles ", "\033[34m", "1107 miles") 
else:
    print(Fore.GREEN + "\nAddress not Found, check address again")
```

Comment: all the "if" run ok but i try to show the part in "Else" when the info its not available

     else: print(Fore.GREEN + "\nAddress not Found, check address again")

just in case of one "destino" its no defined, but show me the sentence even the info its declared.

Comment: The elif statement allows to trigger `else` only if all the conditions weren't met. I believe it would work

Comment: hey bro thanks 4 ur help, runs perfect bro. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use `if - elif - else` format.

If I understood you question correctly, you are trying to print milage for a city entered by user but if the city entered is not from the given three, you want to print "not found" statement.

you can do something like this,

```
if address==destion1:
   print(milage for destion1)
elif address==destion2:
   print(milage for destion2)
elif address==destion3:
   print(milage for destion3)
else:
   print("Not found statement")
```

**Additional suggestions**
It will be a good practice to use a dict or list instead of declaring 3 variables.
And you can shorten the conditional statements, and overall code, like below,

```
destinations = {"dest1" : "milage1", "dest2" : "milage2", "dest3" : "milage3"}

if address in destinations:
   print(f"Milage for {address} is {destinations[address]})
else:
   print("Destination not found")
```

Comment: hmm yeaah thats correct, let me try it and ill tell ok?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki you are correct but, when I started to write my answer there was no answer and I'm very slow in typing.

Comment: But, I added some additional info so probably it is different now.

Comment: hey HIMANSHU  thanks 4 ur help too, runs perfect. thank you very much

Comment: @DanielTQ Glad knowing that, chears !

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
if address in (destino1):
 print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles  ", "\033[34m","935 miles")
elif address in (destino2):
 print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles ", "\033[34m", "1600 miles")
elif address in (destino3):
 print(Fore.WHITE + "\nTotal Miles ", "\033[34m", "1107 miles")        
else:
 print(Fore.GREEN + "\nAddress not Found, check address again")
```